# Strange white bar in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2019, visual-glitch

this is my first post here.
I have this problem that appears only by using Visual Studio (both 2017 and 2019) when working with Unity (2018.3.12f1): there is basically a white column on the left and I don't know what it should be.
I have no clue on how to remove it and it bothers me.
It appeared when I installed the first time VS 2019, since then it appeared on the 2017 version too. I uninstalled both and tried again only with the 2017 version but it is still there.
Does someone any way to remove that? Thanks in advance.
Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDSk6.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colour of that element is set in Tools | Options | Environment | Fonts & Colors under the Text Editor category it is the background colour of "Indicator Margin".

In VS2019's (and VS2017's) dark theme it has a default value of RGB(51, 51, 51).

Maybe your setting is messed up?

PS. Many user settings (including this) are preserved in your profile including across re-installations and versions. These can be reset under Tools | Import or Export Settings.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my "problem". I just disabled it because I don't really need it right now.